# How to show Google Calendar API results with their UI?

Tags: user-interface, calendar, google-calendar-api

For my site, I want to build a feature that allows users to see other users' availability and then schedule a meeting. I'm using the Google Calendar API to pull the user's free/busy times.

I am wondering - is there a way to pull in the Google Calendar UI as well? Ideally, I want a user to enter another user's email, click "see availability" and then be able to see their calendar, with the busy slots blocked off.

Would I have to build that functionality myself, using the API data? Or is there a function for this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google calendar documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/) has mentioned all the possible ways to integrate google calendar into apps.

Hope this helps you integrating calendar into your app

If you have specific UI requirements, you can make use of different UI components available or build your custom UI and integrate the apis to it.
I used [this](https://freefrontend.com/css-calendars/) for making my custom UI